# what are the subgroups of an algebraic group with codimension one

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

let G be an algebraic group. which subgroups of G are codimension one subgroups.

Comment: It is not quite clear what you are asking... The dimension of a closed subgroup depends on the closed subgroup, for example! The FAQ gives some information on how best to ask questions to attract useful answers.

Comment: @bernardshow: You should edit the question (click on the "edit" button), and certainly remove the "What is the dimension of $H$?" (unless you tell us what $H$ is). Your question will probably get closed, but if you edit it and make it into a clear question, then it might et reopened.

Comment: İt is too late to edit. But you are right, my question is

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps it is better to phrase the question in terms of Lie algebras. For instance, if you want to know which are the possible codimension one Lie subalgebras of a given finite dimensional Lie algebra then there is a result of [Tits](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=120308)   which address exactly this.

> Let $\mathfrak g$  be a finite
>   dimensional  Lie algebra over a field of characteristic zero. If 
>   $\mathfrak h$ is a codimension one
>   subalgebra then there exists a 
>   morphism $\phi : \mathfrak g \to
> > \mathfrak{sl}(2)$ with kernel
>   contained in $\mathfrak h$.

This result has been explored by Hoffman to provide a classification of codimension one 
subalgebras of Lie algebras in this [paper](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1076859).

Comment: thanks for your answer jvp. This is the answer of my question.