#  Let G be an affine connected algebraic  group.  When a subvariety of G with codimension one  is a subgroup.   

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, algebraic-groups

Let G be an affine connected algebraic group, and K[G] be its coordinate ring. Let Y  be a subvariety of G defined as a zero set for some  f in K[G]. For which f,  Y is a closed subgroup of G

Comment: This seems curiously similar to this question (of yours), which has a perfectly good answer:

http://mathoverflow.net/questions/68961/what-are-the-subgroups-of-an-algebraic-group-with-codimension-one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is perhaps easiest to express this in terms of Hopf algebras. The coordinate ring $K[G]$ has the structure of a Hopf algebra; the subvariety $Y$ is a closed subgroup of $G$ if and only if the ideal $(f)$ is a Hopf ideal, i.e.
\begin{align*}
\Delta(f) &\in (f) \otimes K[G] + K[G] \otimes (f); \\\\
\epsilon(f) &= 0; \\\\
S(f) &\in (f), 
\end{align*}
where $\Delta$, $\epsilon$ and $S$ are the comultiplication, counit and antipode of the Hopf algebra $K[G]$, respectively.

(See, for instance, Milne's freely available [course notes](http://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/ala.html) on linear algebraic groups.)